# Most efficient way to replace properties of array object based on a map using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of objects with dynamic properties (except Id), what is the best way to replace the property keys with those from a map?

```
// For example, array of objects:
var records = [
  {"Id": "0035w000036m j7oAAA", "Business Phone": "(212) 842-5501"},
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oXXX", "Business Phone": "(212) 842-7777"}
];

// Map to pull replacement property from:
var colHeaderToFieldApiName = {"Business Phone": "Phone"};

// Desired output:
var result = [
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oAAA", "Phone": "(212) 842-5501"},
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oXXX", "Phone": "(212) 842-7777"}
];
```

Here's what I have so far. It works, but just wondering if there's a better way.

```
records.forEach (function (obj) {
  for (const prop in obi) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
      const fieldApiName = colHeaderToFieldApiName [prop];
      if (fieldApiName) {
        obji[fieldApiName] = obj[prop];
        delete obi[prop];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can easily add that code in your img to your question, no images should be used when making a question [Why should I not upload images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried numerous times and still get an error saying it doesn't like the formatting. What could it be do you think?

Comment: Have you tried just highlighting all the code and press Ctrl + k. Do that for only the code part.

Comment: Nevermind, good to go.

Comment: What do you mean by "Most efficient"? Efficient for the machine. like more performant? Or efficient for the developer, like short, intelligible and maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following snippet all keys contained in `newKeys` will replace the given keys of the input array:

```js
var records = [
  {"Id": "0035w000036m j7oAAA", "Business Phone": "(212) 842-5501"},
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oXXX", "Business Phone": "(212) 842-7777"}
];

// Map to pull replacement property from:
var newKeys = {"Business Phone": "Phone"};

// Desired output:
var result = records.map(o=>
 Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(o).map(([k,v])=> [newKeys[k]??k,v] ) )
);
console.log(result);

/* Output
[
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oAAA", "Phone": "(212) 842-5501"},
  {"Id": "0035w000036mj7oXXX", "Phone": "(212) 842-7777"}
];
*/
```

The key replacement works on the basis of the `newKeys` object: only the keys defined in that object will be replaced by their new names. All other keys will will remain the same.

Comment: not sure what some parts of the code do. Does this replace the `Business Phone` key with the `Phone` key only if that key is present in the `newKeys` array?

Comment: somehow `k in newKeys ? newKeys[k] : k` sounds safer to me than relying on "undefined coalescing"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done that in the past.

It is not the fastest implementation, and it doesn't matter unless you are talking about dozens of thousands of key remapping.

If may or may not be the most clear way of doing this for some developers, but it sure is for me, so let me share anyway.

It uses:

- one key replacing function that is curried, because I like this way of function composition.
- one `map` traversal over your list of objects applying this function.

Here it is:

```
const replacekeys = km => o => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k in km ? km[k] : k, v]))
```

Usage:

```
records.map(replacekeys(colHeaderToFieldApiName))
```

Side notes:

- You can use `o.hasOwnProperty(k)` in case you don't want prototypal chain on key containment check;
- If you don't like the [*curried*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) kinda functional style, you can easily change that to `replacekeys = ([km, o]) => ...` and then use it like `records.map(o => replacekeys(colHeaderToFieldApiName, o))`